# why sass styling is applying globalley in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

```
//// ----style.css file code--------

.thead_bg {
    background-color: blue;
}

//// ----sass-style.scss file code-----

.thead_bg {
    background-color: $user-setup-bg-color;
}
```

I have 10 modules in my project and I want to apply dynamic `background-color` in just 2 modules like as 'a' and 'b', and my `style.css` file is globaly attached in my reactJs project and `sass-style.scss` importing into just a and b module. When I am applying dynamic value in a and b module through `sass-style.scss` file, that works good and `background-color` getting applied, but that is not getting applied just 2 component a and b, this color is applying globally all modules however I don't import sass file in other 8 modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are saying, when you are applying through `sass-style.scss`, it is getting applied to all, but that is imported only in two modules, is it ?

Comment: yes exactly, are you know about it

Comment: I need to check that issue